# Are my coretemp "high" and "crit" levels BOTH supposed to be at 100.0°C?

Tags: overheating, temperature, lm-sensors

My friend said everything is fine, but I just think those levels look a bit weird.

Here is the output of sensors:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +36.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +35.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +33.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +43.0°C

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +37.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +31.5°C
```

Answer (score 0):

All your temperatures seem fine.

The "high" and "crit" columns don't actually indicate a temperature, they just indicate what your system would consider "too hot" - if it ever reaches either temperature then your cooling is inadequate.  The round numbers of 100, excessively high 128, and the "high" and "crit" being the same, all imply that these values are guessed and not genuinely known: your system doesn't really have proper knowledge of what maximum temperatures it could sustain.  Most CPUs shouldn't run over around 70 degrees.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to adequately set these thresholds? I doubt my laptop will ever get that hot but I want to make sure it's safe if it ever does happen

Comment: You probably don't have to worry about them because your system is probably coded to automatically throttle or power down the CPU when it becomes too hot despite what this says, but you can get more information at: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/sensors.conf.5.html

Comment: I appreciate that but I can't seem to make sense of that .conf file